# undo-tree: How to map through all nodes programmatically

Tags: undo-tree-mode

I am working on my own new feature request for undo-tree linear undo/redo:  [How to make undo-tree linear -- undo-tree-undo/redo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31779/how-to-make-undo-tree-linear-undo-tree-undo-redo)

I have successfully added two additional gizmos (?) to `cl-defstruct ... undo-tree-node` at the bottom and very end of the definition -- `connect-dots` and `linear-history`.  The new functions are called like this:  `(undo-tree-node-connect-dots (undo-tree-current buffer-undo-tree))` or `(undo-tree-node-history (undo-tree-current buffer-undo-tree))`.

I am adding a list of time-stamps to each node when they are imported from the `buffer-undo-list` with `undo-list-transfer-to-tree`, and also to the final *current* node when using `undo-tree-undo` and `undo-tree-redo`.  The result should be that every node has a list of one or more time-stamps that *never* change -- i.e., I just keep pushing new time-stamps onto whichever node is *current*.

`undo-tree` creates the visualizer buffer by starting from the `root` and following the branch until a branch-point is reached, at which time it branches into 2 or more, etc.  In a nutshell, the parent knows who it siblings are, and the siblings know who the parent is.  I can create a function that does not use a visualizer buffer, which follows the above tree-structure until the very end, but that seems like an inefficient manner to map through all of the nodes.  [I envision this linear undo/redo new feature as being usable irrespective of whether the visualizer buffer has been generated.]

**Q**:  Absent following the tree structure programmatically, is there a more efficient manner to map through each node of the `buffer-undo-tree`?  [E.g., `(dolist (node buffer-undo-tree) (when node ...))`

---

In case anyone was wondering about `connect-dots`, at this time it is just an interesting way of seeing each branch with a different letter and each node is consecutively numbered between root and branch-point, and between each branch-point and leaf.  I may consolidate that feature with the linear visualization, but each node may have more than one time-stamp, so I'll need to think about how to visually represent that.

---

Thanks to the helpful answer by @Tobias below, I came up with the following function that generates a list of all nodes.  `undo-tree-mapc` is designed to apply a function to each node, which is also useful.

```
(defun undo-tree-node-list (&optional transfer-to-tree)
"See also `undo-tree-mapc'."
  (when transfer-to-tree
    (undo-list-transfer-to-tree))
  (let* ((beginning-node (undo-tree-root buffer-undo-tree))
         (stack (list beginning-node))
         n res)
    (while stack
      (setq n (pop stack))
      (push n res)
      (setq stack (append (undo-tree-node-next n) stack)))
    res))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example (can be run in the `*scratch*` buffer):

```el
(progn
  (undo-list-transfer-to-tree)
  (undo-tree-mapc (lambda (node) (message "\n%s" node)) (undo-tree-root buffer-undo-tree)))
```